# Omniauth-facebook Devise Rspec, undefined method `extra' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, omniauth

I'm trying to test omniauth-facebook integration in my app, but i keep getting this failures:

```
Failure/Error: get :facebook
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `extra' for nil:NilClass
 # ./app/models/user.rb:17:in `find_for_facebook_oauth'
 # ./app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:4:in `facebook'
 # ./spec/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller_spec.rb:18:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is the code lines raising the failure:

**user.rb** :

```
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
  data = auth.extra.raw_info # this is line 17
  if user = User.where(:email => data.email).first
    user
  else
    user = User.new
    user
  end
end
```

**omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb** :

```
def facebook
  @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user) # this is line 4

  if @user.persisted?
    flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Facebook"
    sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Authentication was successful, please continue your registration process."
    session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    redirect_to new_user_registration_url
  end
end
```

**omniauth_callbacks_controller_spec.rb** :

```
before(:each) do
  stub_env_for_omniauth

  get :facebook # this is line 18
  @user = User.where(:email => "ghost@nobody.com").first
end

def stub_env_for_omniauth
  request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
  pre = { "omniauth.auth" => { "provider" => "facebook", "uid" => "1234", "credentials" => {"token" => "abcdefg"}, "extra"=>{"raw_info" => {"id" => "1234567", "email" => "ghost@nobody.com", "name" => "Mark", "gender" => "male" }}}}
  env = OmniAuth::AuthHash.new(pre)
  @controller.stub!(:env).and_return(env)
end
```

And this is **spec_helper.rb** :

```
require 'omniauth'
OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `@controller.stub!` I think you should set

```
request.env["omniauth.auth"] = env
```

read more about testing omniauth here https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing

Comment: This helped me to get this output: [http://pastebin.com/8qDx4htX](http://pastebin.com/8qDx4htX)

Answer (score 1):

hey just add following line in **facebook** method

```
def facebook
raise request.env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml
....
end
```

and then check what response you are getting from facebook-omniauth.This might help you to detect the problem.

Comment: This is the output I get [http://pastebin.com/8qDx4htX](http://pastebin.com/8qDx4htX)

Comment: It's the Hash I added for testing (in the stub_env_for_omniauth method)

Comment: there is problem with omniauth hash. You are not getting full details of user thats why you are getting 'extra' field as nil.I think there is no problem in your spec..